# Rails not connecting to Redis (RedisToGo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redistogo

I've been trying to deploy a Rails 4 app to heroku, but still getting the same error:

**Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)**

I'm using RedisToGo and already did the configuration steps showed [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo). The environment variable is correctly set up.

When trying to connect to redis (as shown in the documentation) locally everything works just fine.

Comment: Could you please post your connection code

Comment: I could resolve this by adding the REDIS_URL environment variable instead of REDIS_PROVIDER.

Comment: @ricardoaandres - answer your own question so you can get credit and maybe help someone else! :)

Comment: @CDub yes, I will, but I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question. I will answer it as soon as possible (~7 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve this by adding **REDIS_URL** environment variable instead of **REDISTOGO_URL** or **REDIS_PROVIDER**. Sidekiq official documentation advices to use **PROVIDER_URL**, though I couldn't make it work.